# install oracle client 64bit with pre-installed oracle client 32bit

Tags: oracle

need to ask currently my 64bit win8 is installed 32bit oracle client (sqlplus etc). everything working fine. however this times i am doing some ssrs and need to connect to a oracle db,and thus i have to install 64bit oracle client.

i have downloaded

Version 12.1.0.2.0
Instant Client Package - Basic: All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications

from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

and i have set the PATH to the downloaded "instantclient_12_1"

when i run the ssrs reports, it shows TNS could not resolve etc. so it should be able to run the oracle client 64bit but couldn't locate the tnsnames.ora and so i copied the tnsnames.ora from the 32bit oracle client to the "instantclient_12_1" folder. but it still not working.

*i have rebooted the pc
*have set the PATH to the tnsnames folder as well

kindly advise is there any steps did wrong? 
would like to prefer steps which require less installation of files. because once this is working on my laptop. i will apply the same to the production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` is set in your environment. It shall contain the path to `TNSNames.ora`.

Comment: You are trying to set the PATH variable. You should in addition to the PATH variable set TNS_ADMIN variable.

Comment: Copying the tnsnames.ora does the job (though TNS_ADMIN is better)

Comment: @user2672165 thanks. i have created a TNS_ADMIN variable and pointed to the 32bit tnsnames.ora folder and reboot the laptop. ssrs report is working now.
thanks Patrick

Comment: @Oli then you didn't a very good job copying the tnsnames.ora. That should work too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, i did tried to copy too. to the "instantclient_12_1" folder and any folder within in. not working. or maybe after i copied the tnsnames.ora to "instantclient_12_1" folder and set the TNS_ADMIN to that folder, it will then works.